# MongoDB: Query field and update same field in associated records

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I want to update all records associated with a user to be associated with another user.

So I try the following:

`db.portfolio.find({ user: 'ryan'}, { $set: { user: 'jeff' }}, {multi: true});`

Howerver I get this error:

`error: { "$err" : "Unsupported projection option: user", "code" : 13097 }`

What exactly does that mean and if that isn't the correct why to do what I want, what is? Many thanks.

Comment: you want to use `update` instead of `find`

Comment: Thank you. This was a stupid mistake on my part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said by @Sammaye; should have been `update` not `find`.